# Firebase Login and Login with Apple not linking to same user account

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, firebase-authentication, apple-login

Using SwiftUI, Xcode12.5.1, Swift5.4.2, iOS14.7.1,

My Firebase-Login page shall be extended with other Login possibilities such as Apple-Login (eventually Google-login, Facebook-login etc).

I have an implementation of Firebase-Login that works well.

I extended the LoginView with the `Sign in with Apple` Button.

And this new Apple Login in its basic implementation also works.

Now the problem:

If I log in with Apple, I need to access the corresponding Firebase-user in order to query the correct user-data. Right now, login in with Apple works but the retrieved data is not the user-data of the corresponding Firebase-user.

What I want to achieve:

From a logout-state, I want to

**a) Being able to log in with Firebase Email/Password and sometimes later want to log-out and log in again with Apple.**

**--> and for both cases, I would like to get the same user-data**

**b) Being able to log in with Apple and sometimes later want to log-out and log in again with Firebase Email/Password**

**--> and for both cases, I would like to get the same user-data**

--- THE IDEA ----------

I learned from the [Firebase documentation that there is a way to `link` two login-accounts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/account-linking) that we are able to know that these two accounts are corresponding.

--- THE IMPLEMENTATION -----------

Below is my current implementation for the Apple login:

I learned that you can get userInformation of the corresponding other account in the error of the `link`-callback. But in my case, I get the wrong linkError:

My linkError:

```
The email address is already in use by another account.
```

Instead of:

```
AuthErrorCode.credentialAlreadyInUse
```

For me this doesn't make sense. Especially since I know that I already did log in before with Firebase-Email/Password. Then I logged out and now I tried to log in with Apple.

Shouldn't the `link` method recognise that I am allowed to have been logged in via Firebase-Email/Password before and shouldn't it be ok to have that email being used before ?? I don't understand this linkError.

Questions:

1. In the `link`-callback, why do I get the linkError `The email address is already in use by another account.` instead of `AuthErrorCode.credentialAlreadyInUse` ??
2. What do I need to change in order to make a) work ??
3. How does the implementation look for the b) workflow (i.e. if user logs in to Apple, then logs-out and logs in again with Firebase-Email/Password ??). How do I `link` the two accounts then ??

Here my code:

```
switch state {
case .signIn:
    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error authenticating: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        
        do {
            if let email = try THKeychain.getEmail(),
               let password = try THKeychain.getPassword() {

                let credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: email, password: password)

                if let user = authResult?.user {
                    user.link(with: credential) { (result, linkError) in
                        
                        if let linkError = linkError, (linkError as NSError).code == AuthErrorCode.credentialAlreadyInUse.rawValue {
                            print("The user you're signing in with has already been linked, signing in to the new user and migrating the anonymous users [\(user.uid)] tasks.")
                            
                            if let updatedCredential = (linkError as NSError).userInfo[AuthErrorUserInfoUpdatedCredentialKey] as? OAuthCredential {
                                print("Signing in using the updated credentials")
                                Auth.auth().signIn(with: updatedCredential) { (result, error) in
                                    if let user = result?.user {
                                        
                                        // eventually do a data-migration
                                        user.getIDToken { (token, error) in
                                            if let _ = token {
                                                // do data migration here with the token....
                                                
                                                self.doSignIn(appleIDCredential: appleIDCredential, user: user)
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else if let linkError = linkError {
                            // I END UP HERE !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                            // WHY WHY WHY WHY WHY WHY WHY WHY ????????????????????????
                            print("Error trying to link user: \(linkError.localizedDescription)")
                        }
                        else {
                            if let user = result?.user {
                                self.doSignIn(appleIDCredential: appleIDCredential, user: user)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
                            
        if let user = authResult?.user {
            if let onSignedInHandler = self.onSignedInHandler {
                onSignedInHandler(user)
            }
        }
    }
case .link:
    // t.b.d.
case .reauth:
    // t.b.d.
}
```

Comment: "Firebase Login and Login with Apple not linking to same user account"  Is that really surprising?

Comment: yes it is surprising - especially since the Firebase-documentation explicitly says `You can allow users to sign in to your app using multiple authentication providers by linking auth provider credentials to an existing user account. Users are identifiable by the same Firebase user ID regardless of the authentication provider they used to sign in. For example, a user who signed in with a password can link a Google account and sign in with either method in the future. Or, an anonymous user can link a Facebook account and then, later, sign in with Facebook to continue using your app.`

Comment: So why is my code (that does link Firebase-Email/Password Login to Apple-Login) not pinpoint to the very same user ???

Comment: From the [Firebase Documentation: Apple Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/apple#reauthentication_and_account_linking) - *And, you can use linkWithCredential() to link different identity providers to existing accounts* and then see [Linking](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/account-linking#link-auth-provider-credentials-to-a-user-account)

Comment: I don't understand your answer:  I DID USE `user.link(with: credential) { (result, linkError) in ... }` in my example. And there is no `linkWithCredential()` method but only `user.link(with: credential)`.... Can you please give a better example than just links to documentation that I already consultet and had mentioned in the original post already. Thank you.

Comment: See https://peterfriese.de/replicating-reminder-swiftui-firebase-part4/ for instructions how to deal with “ The email address is already in use by another account.”. Essentially, you need to re-run the linking with the updated credential provided in the error object.

Comment: That is exactly what I intended to do (i.e. `re-run the linking with the updated credential provided in the error object`). However, the error object does not contain any kind of `updated credentials`. I started a [new stackoverflow-question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68781490/3826232) to explain even better what is going on. Maybe you can comment there. Thank you very much